# Does "possibly remote after trial period" really count as remote?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

This is at least the second such posting I've seen today:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112313/teamwork-desk-software-engineer-teamworkcom

In particular, the top of the post says:

> ***Working remotely is a possible option decided on a case-by-case basis after the trial period has been completed. Relocation is preferred.***

**Does "possibly remote after an on-site trial period" count as remote?**  I don't mind flying to an office for an interview, occasional meetings, or even training, but "trial period" doesn't sound like any of that.

It reads to me like "We want to get the attention of people looking for Remote jobs, so we'll dangle this carrot in front of people, just to get them to apply, but we really don't want to offer it."

As someone who is looking strictly for *actual* remote positions, I find this sort of bait-and-switch highly annoying. Should I be flagging such posts, or does this fit within the guidelines that employers are given?

Comment: If they offer the possibility of a remote without offering a remote after a trial, then they're lying.

Comment: I wouldn't be "flying to an office" for an interview. On another note, here is how I see it. Once they suck all the knowledge out of you, geez, ya know, things didn't work out.

Comment: "Maybe XYZ after a trial period that benefits us a lot more than it benefits you" is just barely different enough from that old parenting standby of "maybe we'll go to Disneyland" that few people recognize it for what it is: a lie. Trial periods and internships nowadays are used as a way to get cheap temporary labor. There is no light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: No... this can't be classified as a remote job... "possibility for remote in future" can be added as a perk for a normal job listing, but it shouldn't be classified as remote.

Comment: Oh, come on, it is an advertisement.  It isn't anything different from a beer ad that promises "tastes great and less filling".  A claim that's always true as long as there is Guinness Draught around.  Which you'd better get used to from the looks of it, they are not hiding anything.

Comment: @HansPassant The goal of SO careers is to provide a service that *developers* want to use, and to use that pool of developers to convince companies to pay premium to get access to said developers.  Unlike most "ads", where the ads are not the reason why people watch TV: instead, you are offered something else (entertainment), and in exchange you have to watch ads.  In that case, ads can be slimy, because the primary target "market" of the ads system is the ad-sellers.  In a system where you want to convince people to come to just look at ads, you have to have high quality ads to work.

Comment: Sure.  The goal of careers is to keep the lights on, the servers running and the company in business.  They make a living off paying advertisers, they are the customers.  SO users don't pay and are not the customers, they are the trade goods.  Keeping both the customers and the goods happy, well, not so easy.  Spinning a good story is 90% of the battle.  Fwiw, they tried to get SO users to pay a long time ago, 50 bucks/year iirc, didn't work.

Comment: Is this the "*free app\** (\*in-app purchases)" of Careers?

Comment: @Yakk if you're not paying (to make use of Careers), you *are* the product.

Comment: This sounds more like a company that might allow employees to work *from home*, not *work remotely*.

Comment: A product that has the ability to choose a different market if it doesn't like the customers, @Glorfindel.

Comment: @duskwuff: I've seen a number of those, too... "Work remote, two days a week!"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After the positive (negative?) reaction here, I went ahead and flagged the post, and this morning received this response from StackOverflow via email:

> Thanks for taking the time to flag the listing, I’ve amended the remote flag and spoken to their account manager to ensure the client fully understands the implications of offering remote work.
>
> Cheers!

Answer (score 77):

If working remotely is a perk that is offered only to their tenured people, then listing an opening as possibly remote is deceptive.  It's not an opening for a remote position, it's an opening for an on-site position with a career track that leads to remote positions (among others).

This seems no different from including the first 12 months of merit raises in "starting salary".

Comment: Agreed: a remote opportunity is one that is *at most* requiring a short initial training period - i.e. low single digit weeks. Thereafter it is remote. Or *not*.

Answer (score 27):

This job sounds actually *less* of a "remote" job than many normal/onsite ones.A remote opportunity is one that is at most requiring a short initial training period - i.e. low single digit weeks. Thereafter it is remote. Or not.

In *this* case it is not only *not* remote - it also offers clues that they have significant reluctance to make it so.  Many standard jobs are actually more open to the remote option after some period than this one.

Answer (score 7):

Why do people want remote jobs? So they can keep living where they live now. A job with an on-site "trial" (presumably 3+ months) doesn't provide that. They'd need to move, and then *maybe* move back. So, basically, this doesn't meet the needs of the people looking for remote jobs.

Answer (score 2):

The Post:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112313/teamwork-desk-software-engineer-teamworkcom

Should be flag to remove the "Remote" keyword from the job listing.

Moving to Cork, Ireland with the possibility of "Remote" is unacceptable.

Having this at the top in bold puts the possibility of real "Remote" to about 0.05% chance at best:

> Working remotely is a **possible** option decided on a **case-by-case** basis
>   after the **trial period** has been completed. 
>   **Relocation is preferred**.

To top it off they are a

**Visa Sponsor**

Which means they are basically looking for workers from low paying foreign countries.

Since the post does not include any location requirements near their physical location one can say for sure they are looking for Visa workers to offer them low wages.

All references to "Remote" in the job listing should be removed.

Comment: Considering Ireland is a EU country, "Visa sponsor" is _highly_ suspect. There are about half a billion Europeans that don't need a visum.